# Unable to sum column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using this below query to sum my column values.

**Query:**

```
select 
'$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),cast(round(isnull(sum([Share_Invest]),0),0)as     MONEY),1), '.00', '') [Investment], 
'$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),cast(round(isnull(sum([Profit_Share]),0),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') [Profit Amount],
[Variance] = '$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),cast(round(isnull(sum([Share_Invest]-[Profit_Share]),0),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') 
from Finance
```

for first column its fine and sum is showing up. But my Profit_Share column has null values and datas too and this doesn't sum column values.

Can anyone correct me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: no error in the sql syntax, could you provide a sample data and result that u want?

Comment: to be expected. `null` is contagious, and any operations involving an sql `null` (math, concatenation, comparisons, etc...) all become `null` themselves.

Comment: "my Profit_Share column has null values and datas too". What do you means by "datas"? Text data?

Comment: You probably want to do it the other way, not `isnull(sum(`, but `sum(isnull(`

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag because the syntax suggests SQL Server.

Comment: NULLs should be handled correctly for the first two columns.  I can see an issue with the third.  What is the issue with the second column?

Comment: @Joseph B - Its not text data, they are numbers.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - For second column I don't see the sum values showing up unlike first column.

Comment: nothing wrong with this query, i got the sum result (Mine is using Sql-server 2012)

Comment: Try @TomasPastircak answer, that is the solution, I guess... May be you are getting the `NULL` in between the records, which will not `SUM` with other values

Comment: @Tomas Pastircak - When I tried the query I get an error saying `the isnull function requires two arguments`

Comment: WOW... You need to do like this, `SUM(ISNULL(val,0))`

Comment: @Bharadwaj - `'$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),cast(round(sum(isnull([Profit_Share]),0),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') [Profit Amount],` I STILL GET THE ERROR

Comment: ISNULL needs to get one of the 0s as an argument, i.e. `'$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),cast(round(sum(isnull([Profit_Share],0)),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') [Profit Amount],
`

Comment: @TomasPastircak - I still see the same result.

Comment: Do one thing, just bring "sum(isnull(Profit_Share,0))" to the application and use formats from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with your query, 
but probably you will get trouble if the [Share_Invest] or [Profit_Share] values are in decimals ($50.05, $10.10)

Assumming the @finance table is your finance table:

```
 declare @finance table
(
 id int identity,
 [Share_Invest] money,
 [Profit_Share] money
)


insert into @finance
select '50.05', '10.00' union all
select '20.05', '5.00' union all
select null, '5.00' union all
select null, null union all
select '10.00', null union all
select null, null

-- your query
select 
'$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),cast(round(isnull(sum([Share_Invest]),0),0)as     MONEY),1), '.00', '') [Investment], 
'$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),cast(round(isnull(sum([Profit_Share]),0),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') [Profit Amount],
[Variance] = '$ ' + REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),cast(round(isnull(sum([Share_Invest]-[Profit_Share]),0),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') 
from @Finance

/*
Investment Profit Amount Variance
---------- ------------- ---------
$ 80       $ 20          $ 60
*/

-- modified query
select
'$ ' + cast(sum(isnull([Share_invest],0)) as nvarchar(5))  as [Investment]
,'$ ' + cast(sum(isnull([Profit_Share],0)) as nvarchar(5))  as [Profit Amount]
, '$ ' + cast(sum(isnull([Share_invest],0) - isnull([Profit_Share],0)) as nvarchar(max)) as [Variance]
from @finance

/*
Investment Profit Amount Variance
---------- ------------- ---------
$ 80.10    $ 20.00       $ 60.10
*/
```

I remove the cast (As money), and round